# Cordova 2.9 barcode-scanner plugin not reaching callback after scan on galaxy S4

Tags: cordova

This is quite bizzare imo...

I have a simple app to scan QR codes that works fine on my Nexus running AOKP 4.2.2
However, it doesn't seem to want to complete the scan on a Stock Galaxy S4.

The app launches the scanner and scans the code, but never executes any callback function.
Simply just closes and returns the homescreen. No logging that indicates an error from what I can tell.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inadvertently enabled "Do not keep activities" which caused this behavior....rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try turning it off?

logcats are the most important aspect of debugging on Android.

You can use them to get error messages when your app crashed or to print your own debugging information.